# iOS coredata predicate: How to predicate the primitive value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a bit a nasty problem. In coredata I have an entity called "Category" and I want to have a default category, a user cannot delete, edit etc. This default category is called "0_default_category" (stored in the constant kSettingsLocalizedDefaultCategory) and this name gets replaced by a localized string when displayed to the user. For that I have overwritten the getter:

```
-(NSString *)name
{
    if([[self primitiveValueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:kSettingsLocalizedDefaultCategory]){
        return NSLocalizedString(kSettingsLocalizedDefaultCategory, nil);
    } else {
        return [self primitiveValueForKey:@"name"];
    }
}
```

Now of course I want to use the predicate on the constant and not the localized string! But this uses the predicate on the localized string (so my getter is called, which I don't want..)

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != %@", kSettingsLocalizedDefaultCategory];
```

Any idea how I can predicate the primitive value?

Comment: in you predicate creation setters and getters of entity are not used, you can dump it as NSLog("%@",request.predicate ) to exam, perhaps your data is corrupted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are conflating two separate issues. One is the fact that you have some special logic (your constant) to automatically display a localized string. The other is to return the value stored in the attribute `name`.

Ideally, these should be separated to make these two issues explicit. Thus, you should not override the getter of `name` but instead just create a custom method (or a derived attribute, according to your needs) with a different name.

```
-(NSString*)displayName {
   return [self.name isEqualToString:kConstant] ? 
    NSLocalizedString(kConstant) : self.name;
}
```

Use `displayName` if you want to display your name using your custom logic, and keep the predicate as

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != %@", kConstant];
```

Comment: hmm easy solution :-) Thanks!